# Knockout.js - valueUpdate: afterkeydown too fast

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a search bar that data binds results in a grid using afterkeydown. However, the binding is happening too quickly. Users only have time for a single key press before the results start to populate. I have a Block UI element that prevents interaction with the page while results are loading, thus stopping the search query at a single character until results are loaded. Is there another method I should be using or a way to extend the time shortly so a full query can be entered?

```
<input id="search-btn" class="form-control" 
    data-bind="value: searchTerm, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

Comment: Rather than `value: searchTerm, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'`, better to use `textInput: searchTerm`.

Answer (score 1):

On your `searchTerm` observable you can add an extender called `rateLimit`. This will add a delay before the value is updated.

```
searchTerm = ko.observable(...).extend({ 
    rateLimit: { 
        timeout: 800, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" 
    },  
});
```

[Reference](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html)

Comment: Thanks, where exactly can this extend be placed? When I'm defining the searchTerm observable?

Comment: Yes you can add it when you first define the observable or any time after by using searchTerm.extend(...)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wrap the observable like this :

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.instantaneousValue = ko.observable();
    this.delayedValue = ko.pureComputed(this.instantaneousValue)
        .extend({ rateLimit: { method: "notifyWhenChangesStop", timeout: 400 } });
 
    // Keep a log of the throttled values
    this.loggedValues = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.delayedValue.subscribe(function (val) {
        if (val !== '')
            this.loggedValues.push(val);
    }, this);
}
```

As you see, the delayed value is the actual value which will be updated with some delay and subscribe will also fire with that delay.
You can refer here : https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html